# Excel VBA Run-time error '70': Permission denied (If I run)

Tags: excel, vba

When I run the next Code it triggers an alert that says Error '70', but when I run it Step by Step It works Perfectly!!!!

Sub Arribos()

```
Dim IE As Object
Dim objElement As Object
Dim objCollection As Object
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Double
Dim K As Double
Dim S As Double
Dim l As Object
Dim Cols As Integer
Dim SPAN_ULTIMO_NUM As Integer
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

    ' OPTIMIZO

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    ' BORRO HOJA TAMS ARRIBOS

Cols = Hoja9.Range("R1").Value

If Cols <> 1 Then
For i = 2 To Cols
    Hoja9.Rows(2).Delete Shift:=xlUp
Next
End If

Cols = Hoja12.Range("R1").Value
If Cols <> 1 Then
For i = 2 To Cols
    Hoja12.Rows(2).Delete Shift:=xlUp
Next
End If

' ABRO EXPLORER Y COMIENZO

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application") ' Crea el objeto (abre IE)

IE.Visible = True ' Si pones False, no abre la ventana

IE.Navigate "http://www.tams.com.ar/organismos/" ' URL de TAMS

Do While IE.Busy ' Espera mientras esta cargando
Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
Loop

Set objCollection = IE.Document.GetElementsByTagName("select") ' Encuentra todos los <select>

Do While IE.Busy
Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
Loop

OCLength = objCollection.Length
i = 0

While i < OCLength ' Mientras haya inputs...
  If objCollection(i).Name = "ddlMovTp" Then ' Arribos
      objCollection(i).Value = "A"
Else
    If objCollection(i).Name = "ddlAeropuerto" Then ' Aeropuerto EZE
        objCollection(i).Value = "EZE"
    Else
       If objCollection(i).Name = "ddlVentanaH" Then ' Ventana Horaria -48hs
            objCollection(i).Value = "-24"
            objCollection(i).FireEvent ("onchange")
       End If
    End If
End If
i = i + 1
Wend

Do While IE.Busy
Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
Loop

K = 2

SPAN_ULTIMO = Right(IE.Document.querySelector("tr.Pager td").textContent, 1)
If SPAN_ULTIMO <> "." Then
SPAN_ULTIMO = CInt(SPAN_ULTIMO)
End If

SPAN_SELECCIONADO = CInt(IE.Document.querySelector("tr.Pager td span").textContent)
While SPAN_ULTIMO <> SPAN_SELECCIONADO

' Cuando es un número me lo toma, cuando no es no!

SPAN_ULTIMO = Right(IE.Document.querySelector("tr.Pager td").textContent, 1)
If SPAN_ULTIMO <> "." Then
    SPAN_ULTIMO = CInt(SPAN_ULTIMO)
End If

SPAN_SELECCIONADO = CInt(IE.Document.querySelector("tr.Pager td span").textContent)

i = 0
Do While IE.Busy
    Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
Loop

Set objCollection = IE.Document.getelementsbyclassname("tdBlanco")(0).GetElementsByTagName("td") ' Encuentra la tabla de Tams
S = objCollection.Length
While i < S             ' Mientras haya <tr> ...
    j = 1
    While j < 17 And i < S
        Do While IE.Busy
            Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
        Loop
        **Hoja9.Cells(K, j).Value = objCollection(i).textContent**
        Do While IE.Busy
            Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
        Loop
        j = j + 1
        i = i + 1
    Wend
    K = K + 1
Wend
K = K - 1

' Paso de Ventana
If SPAN_ULTIMO <> SPAN_SELECCIONADO Then
    IE.Document.querySelector("tr.Pager td span").NextSibling.NextSibling.Click
End If
' Espera mientras esta cargando
While IE.Busy
    Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
Wend
Wend


Cols = Hoja9.Range("R1").Value
If Cols <> 1 Then
For i = 2 To Cols
    If Hoja9.Cells(i, 1) = "Cía." Then
        Rows(i & ":" & i).Delete Shift:=xlUp
    End If
Next
Cols = Hoja9.Range("R1").Value
Hoja9.Rows(Cols & ":" & Cols).Delete Shift:=xlUp
End If
IE.Quit

End Sub
```

The mistakes is in this part of the code:

```
    **Hoja9.Cells(K, j).Value = objCollection(i).textContent**
```

Line 115.

Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque esta en Ingles